# Why co-NP is not a subset of NP

Tags: complexity-theory

Someone asked me this question and I found I could not answer it even after spending some time re-reading my college textbooks. Specifically, here is the definition of co-NP in many text books:

Definition 1

"a problem A is in co-NP if and only if there is a polynomial time procedure V (·, ·) and a polynomial bound p() such that x ∈ A if and only if ∀y : |y| ≤ p(|x|), V (x, y) = 1"

1. Doesn't this mean that if A is in co-NP, then it MUST have a certificate (because every y would be a certificate) and therefore, A is also in NP?
2. With some thoughts, I am not sure the above definition is correct. Given the following definition of NP:

Definition 2

"a decision problem A is in NP if and only if there is a polynomial time
procedure V (·, ·) and a polynomial time bound p() such that x ∈ A if and only if ∃y.|y| ≤ p(|x|) ∧ V (x, y) = 1"

The straightforward definition for co-NP seems to be:

Definition 3

"a decision problem A is in co-NP if and only if there is a polynomial time bound p() such that x ∈ A if and only if ∀y : |y| ≤ p(|x|) there does NOT exist a polynomial time procedure V(.,.) such that V (x, y) = 1"

However, Definition 3 is not equivalent to Definition 1, because V(.,.) can be undecidable. Am I missing anything? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Doesn't this mean that if A is in co-NP, then it MUST have a certificate (because every y would be a certificate) and therefore, A is also in NP?

No. V is not a verifier for problem A in the sense of the definition of NP. For V to be a verifier in that sense, we would need to be able to determine x ∈ A by finding a single y such that V(x, y) = 1. With this V, we need to check all possible values of y.

Your proposed "straightforward definition" of co-NP is wrong. For any problem A, we could pick V to be the procedure that ignores its arguments and immediately returns 1. Thus, by your definition, no problems would be in co-NP.

Comment: Thanks for the answers!

Comment: BTW, can we say definition 2 (which was copied from a textbook) is incomplete because it does not state that if x is not in A then V(x,y) = 0?

Comment: @jzl106: No. That follows from the "if and only if", which indicates a bidirectional implication.

Comment: So based on that Definition 2, can we say V(x,y) is always 0 for any x NOT in A? Can it be undecidable?

Comment: @jzl106: For a problem A in NP and its polynomial-time verifier V, V(x, y) will be 0 for any x not in A. It can't be undecidable, since V is polynomial-time. If you have more questions, please don't ask them in the comment section. Post a new question, ideally on cs.stackexchange.com, which is a more appropriate site than Stack Overflow for pure-theory questions.